# When removing model data from a db everything but the primary key is getting deleted, how can i remove all of it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a listbox system where the operator can select exercises in a users regime and delete them. Currently when `RemoveExercises` is called it deletes all of the data associated with the `RegimeItem` but the `RegimeItemID`.
For the RemoveExercises function, i have started using a Session so that the RequestedExercises listbox is updated with the changes made (the adding and removing of exercises). Any help or suggestions as to why the entire model item is not being deleted is appreciated. As you can see below, the table data shows the "deleted" item but the item ID still remains.

[image]

**Controller(cs)**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ExerciseIndex(int id, UserExerciseViewModel vmodel)
    {
        User user = db.Users.Find(id);
        UserExerciseViewModel model = new UserExerciseViewModel { AvailableExercises = GetAllExercises(), RequestedExercises = ChosenExercises(user, vmodel) };
        model.UserID = user.UserID;
        Session["UserExerciseViewModel"] = model;
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ExerciseIndex(UserExerciseViewModel model, string add, string remove, string send, int id, RegimeItem item)//, User rUser) //int userID
    //public ActionResult ExerciseIndex(UserExerciseViewModel model, string add, string remove, string send, int id, RegimeItem item)
    {

        UserExerciseViewModel model2 = (UserExerciseViewModel)(Session["UserExerciseViewModel"]);
        model.RequestedExercises = model2.RequestedExercises;
        model.AvailableExercises = model2.AvailableExercises;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(add))
            AddExercises(model, id);
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(remove))
            RemoveExercises(model, id);
        return RedirectToAction("ExerciseIndex", new { id = model2.UserID, vmodel = model2 });
    }

    void RemoveExercises(UserExerciseViewModel model, int id)
    {
        var userExerciseViewModel = (UserExerciseViewModel)(Session["UserExerciseViewModel"]);
        foreach (int selected in model.RequestedSelected)
        {
            if (model.RequestedSelected != null)
            {
                User user = db.Users.Find(id);
                RegimeItem item = db.RegimeItems.Find(selected); // ---deletes the user associated with regimeitem
                item.RegimeExercise = this.GetAllExercises().FirstOrDefault(i => i.ExerciseID == selected); //--this removes the regimeexercise
                user.RegimeItems.Remove(item);
            }
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    private List<Exercise> GetAllExercises()
    {
        return db.Exercises.ToList();
    }

    private List<RegimeItem> ChosenExercises(User user, UserExerciseViewModel model)
    {
        return db.Users
     .Where(u => u.UserID == user.UserID)
     .SelectMany(u => u.RegimeItems)
     .ToList();
    }
```

**Models(cs)**

```
 public class User
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public ICollection<RegimeItem> RegimeItems { get; set; }
        public User()
        {
            this.RegimeItems = new List<RegimeItem>();
        } 
    }
    public class RegimeItem
    {
        public int RegimeItemID { get; set; }
        public Exercise RegimeExercise { get; set; }
    }
```

**ViewModel(cs)**

```
public class UserExerciseViewModel
{
    public List<Exercise> AvailableExercises { get; set; }
    public List<RegimeItem> RequestedExercises { get; set; }
    public int? SelectedExercise { get; set; }
    public int[] AvailableSelected { get; set; }
    public int[] RequestedSelected { get; set; }
    public string SavedRequested { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following change should fix it:

```
void RemoveExercises(UserExerciseViewModel model, int id)
{
    var userExerciseViewModel = (UserExerciseViewModel)(Session["UserExerciseViewModel"]);
    foreach (int selected in model.RequestedSelected)
    {
        if (model.RequestedSelected != null)
        {
            User user = db.Users.Find(id);
            RegimeItem item = db.RegimeItems.Find(selected);
            item.RegimeExercise = this.GetAllExercises().FirstOrDefault(i => i.ExerciseID == selected); //--this removes the regimeexercise
            user.RegimeItems.Remove(item); //deletes the user's regimeitem
            db.RegimeItems.Remove(item); //removes the regimeitem itself 
        }
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i have updated the question to show a segment of the table data, it deletes the other properties but it doesn't delete the RegimeItemID. I apologise for my poor naming conventions, and the path of the session is quite confusing for myself also.  I think the answer to my problem lies within `RemoveExercises` as i managed to remove the other model properties from within there.

Comment: @Nilmag Which table is that in your screenshot?

Comment: Its the table for RegimeItem

Comment: I changed the answer to what you are looking for.